# flatpak , gnome-keyring initial state, Collection login doesn't exist

Tags: d-bus, chrome-book, chrome-os, gnome-keyring

env is arm64 + Linux penguin 5.15.... aarch64

at upgrade time on pithos app, i needed to install gnome-keyring. Pithos is the FIRST flatpak app running on this new chromebook (dev linux working fine). an older, non-flatpak version of pithos ran fine.  Newbie hopes it all works where i login to linux, the keyring daemon starts and runs in a way that the keychain is unlocked and on a call over dbus from the pithos app, the credentials from chain + keyring automagically provide the app with appropriate password.

BUT...

when i login as linux user to the chromebook ( pin is used here and NOT password ) i expect to see the keyring daemon running and IT IS NOT RUNNING.

the keyring daemon does NOT START until i try to start the pithos app up. The app fails on the delegated chain of login with credentials provided by dbus call and read access to the  keyring where the pithos password is kept ...

After attempted startup of pithos app, the keyring daemon finally appears :

```
rob@penguin:~$ ps aux | grep key
rob       1332  0.2  0.1 237724  8304 ?        Sl   08:47   0:00 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --foreground --components=secrets
```

but the app (pithos) fails on the dbus call not providing the password:

```
    (pithos:2): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:33:03.075: Theme parsing error: adapta.css:11225:65: Using one color stop with linear-gradient() is deprecated.
    ERROR - util:get_account_password:133 - Failed to lookup password sync, Error: g-io-error-quark: user interaction failed (0)
    ERROR - util:on_password_store_finish:149 - Failed to store password, Error: g-io-error-quark: user interaction failed (0)
    ERROR - util:get_account_password:133 - Failed to lookup password sync, Error: g-io-error-quark: user interaction failed (0)
```

Not an expert on dbus debug but my dbus log has :

```
Jun 10 14:44:19 penguin dbus-daemon[194]: [session uid=1000 pid=194] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Flatpak' unit='flatpak-session-helper.service' requested by ':1.36' (uid=1000 pid=2419 comm="flatpak run io.github.Pithos " label="kernel")
Jun 10 14:44:19 penguin systemd[123]: Starting flatpak session helper...
Jun 10 14:44:19 penguin dbus-daemon[194]: [session uid=1000 pid=194] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Flatpak'
Jun 10 14:44:19 penguin systemd[123]: Started flatpak session helper.
Jun 10 14:44:19 penguin systemd[123]: Started app-flatpak-io.github.Pithos-2419.scope.
Jun 10 14:44:24 penguin xdg-desktop-por[1294]: Backend call failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Failed: Collection login doesn't exist
Jun 10 14:45:39 penguin xdg-desktop-por[1294]: Backend call failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Failed: Collection login doesn't exist
Jun 10 14:45:39 penguin xdg-desktop-por[1294]: Backend call failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Failed: Collection login doesn't exist
pretty clear fail in the above log:

    Jun 10 08:47:10 penguin gnome-keyring-daemon[1332]: couldn't access control socket: /run/user/1000/keyring/control: No such file or directory
    Jun 10 08:47:10 penguin gnome-keyring-d[1332]: couldn't access control socket: /run/user/1000/keyring/control: No such file or directory
```

but i do not know what todo .. should i install seahorse or libsecret-tools??

how do i proceed/debug the issue with proper access via dbus to the keyring?

re: the keyring, i think github is able to use it because it calls for the keychain passwd and proceeds with a push to a remote but git is NOT run via flatpak:

```
Jun 10 11:03:32 penguin gpg-agent[2152]: gpg-agent (GnuPG) 2.2.27 starting in supervised mode.
Jun 10 11:03:32 penguin gpg-agent[2152]: using fd 3 for std socket (/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent)
Jun 10 11:03:32 penguin gpg-agent[2152]: using fd 4 for ssh socket (/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh)
Jun 10 11:03:32 penguin gpg-agent[2152]: using fd 5 for browser socket (/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.browser)
Jun 10 11:03:32 penguin gpg-agent[2152]: using fd 6 for extra socket (/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra)
Jun 10 11:03:32 penguin gpg-agent[2152]: listening on: std=3 extra=6 browser=5 ssh=4
Jun 10 11:03:32 penguin dbus-daemon[194]: [session uid=1000 pid=194] Activating service name='org.gnome.keyring.SystemPrompter' requested by ':1.24' (uid=1000 pid=2154 comm="pinentry --display :0 " label="kernel")
...
Jun 10 11:04:42 penguin gnome-keyring-daemon[1332]: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/Default_5fkeyring/1, but it's already registered
Jun 10 11:04:42 penguin gnome-keyring-d[1332]: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/Default_5fkeyring/1, but it's already registered
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

1. install `seahorse`
2. create a new keychain with name=`login`
3. unlock the chain in #2

Next time I tried to start the app, I was prompted by the app for a password that `dbus` + `gnome-keyring` added to proper chain and all is good.

After the above, `login.keyring` exists and is and unlocked, so I guess I solved it.

```shellsession
rob@penguin:~$ ls -l .local/share/keyrings/
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 rob rob  15 Jun  9 14:57 default
-rw------- 1 rob rob 813 Jun 11 13:19 Default_keyring.keyring
-rw------- 1 rob rob 327 Jun 11 13:24 login.keyring
-rw------- 1 rob rob   0 Jun 10 11:04 user.keystore
```